# Subset does not work with some numeric values but with others

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I ran in a very strange problem I don't know how to solve and have never seen. I can subset a `data.frame` for some but not for other numeric values.

Here is the data I use:

```
library(dplyr)
ws <- seq(0, 1, by=.1)
kombos <- expand.grid(weightjaw2 = ws,
                  weightjaw3 = ws) %>% as.data.frame
kombos$kombi <- 1:nrow(kombos)
kombos$weightjaw2 <- as.numeric(kombos$weightjaw2)
kombos$weightjaw3 <- as.numeric(kombos$weightjaw3)
class(kombos$weightjaw2)

[1] "numeric"
```

Now, I need to subset this `data.frame`. This works well, say for example, the value `0.1`.

```
kombos %>% filter(weightjaw2==0.1)
   weightjaw2 weightjaw3 kombi
1         0.1        0.0     2
2         0.1        0.1    13
3         0.1        0.2    24
4         0.1        0.3    35
5         0.1        0.4    46
6         0.1        0.5    57
7         0.1        0.6    68
8         0.1        0.7    79
9         0.1        0.8    90
10        0.1        0.9   101
11        0.1        1.0   112
```

Strangely enough, this does not work for values of `0.3`, `0.6`, and `0.7`.

```
kombos %>% filter(weightjaw2==0.3)
[1] weightjaw2 weightjaw3 kombi     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

The same holds for `subset(kombos, weightjaw2==0.3)`. Why is that and how can I solve this?

**EDIT**

I solved this using `dyplyr::near()`:

```
kombos %>% filter(near(weightjaw2, 0.3))
```

Comment: It would  be a floating point issue  You can check the difference `kombos$weightjaw2 - 0.3`

Comment: Duplicate of [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: One option is to `filter` after converitng to `character` `kombos %>% filter(as.character(weightjaw2) == 0.3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `==` requires both lhs and rhs to  be exactly equal.  The 'weightjaw2' column is not exactly equal to 0.3 due  to the  precision checks.   One option is to convert the column to  `character` in `filter` to subset the rows

```
library(dplyr)
kombos %>%
    filter(as.character(weightjaw2) == 0.3)
```